# Recommendations for putting obscure language in title

Tags: discussion, tags, title

Some users have the idea that under no circumstances should the language be put in the title of a question. In general, I agree with this, but in the case of more obscure or specialized languages I see an argument for putting the language in the title.

For example, if the question concerns C/C++/C#, Java, Python, etc, fine, the tag is sufficient, but for questions involving less common languages (Go, Erlang, Matlab, ML, etc) I think the asker should warn people in the title.

More than once I have stumbled into questions I thought were normal, but it turned out to be Erlang-specific or some such, so I had to back out. For example, if the question is something like "QuickSort implementation not working due to stack overflow", it's annoying to enter the question then find out its his *Erlang* QuickSort implementation that the question is about.

Comment: Why are tags not enough here? I'm following the Python tag, so I'm not likely to come across many Erlang questions. The tags on the exceptions are good enough for me.

Comment: You could always put the Erlang tag in your Ignored Tags list, and those questions won't even show up on the front page.

Comment: It comes up whenever you are following any non-language-specific tag. So, for example, I follow "algorithms". Usually such questions are either language-agnostic or in a common language, so I am not looking for a language tag. If some guy posts an algorithm question which is obscure-language-specific, thats where I get trapped.

Comment: We really prefer that people use the tag system for this.  The most common tag (which is usually the language tag) is prepended to the beginning of the title for Google Search purposes, so there really should be no need for a question tag in the title.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Oh, yeah, good idea. Try to figure out every tag I am *not* interested. Let's see, how many of those are there, 5,000?

Comment: How would adding the language's name to the title remedy this problem, though? You see the tags underneath the question title already. Why is that not enough? How would polluting the title be better?

Comment: Because I don't always read the tags, but I always read the title. Saying, oh you should ALWAYS read the tags, just in case its that one wierd question about COBOL, is impractical. 99% of posts are not COBOL-specific, so I not going to start scrutinizing tags, just on the off chance is it obscure-language-specific. That would reduce the number of questions I could scan.

Comment: @TylerDurden: Add favorite tags. It should fill your main page with your favorite tags, and only a few are of tags that you don't want. For the few that you don't want, add those that have high question count to Ignored list, use asterisk if necessary. You only have to set up once, and be good.

Comment: @nhahtdh I do use favorite tags, but like many SO users I also scan general questions. Besides I don't want to be screening out all Erlang or Matlab questions. In some cases I might want to answer those. I just want a warning first.

Comment: Honestly, you not reading the tags seems like it's your problem, not ours.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Saying, read the tags, is not practical. First of all, it reduces the number of questions I can scan if I read all tags. I have to scan a lot of questions before finding one I can answer, so this would cut down my productivity. Also, it is VERY RARE that a tag value would change my decision to read a question. 99% of the time the title is enough, so it is not efficient for me to be reading every tag on the off chance it is important.

Comment: If it's "VERY RARE" that a tag will change your mind about reading a question, then that must mean that this whole problem is very rare too, so not worth caring about.

Comment: @Billy Mailman I totally agree with you, its minor quibble that only comes up once in a while, but I think it is worth getting out there, hey, its ok to put a keyword in a title, if you are asking about something wierd or offbeat.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the first rule of the ignored tags list is that you do not talk about the ignored tags list.

Comment: Let's say this was accepted and we went down that route, who defines what is weird and/or quirky? Tags are there for a reason, if you look at them when scanning the page, you will hardly notice the slowdown.

Comment: @Tyler Except it's not ok. Putting the language in the title is an attempt to solve a problem (categorizing questions so people can find ones they're interested in, and avoid ones they're not interested in) we already have a robust, officially-supported solution for. Just glance at the tags on a question after you've seen the title. Problem solved.

Comment: Is it worth changing the entire way the tagging system works for a site of seven million questions, a convention grown out of five years of hard work and hundreds of discussions, so one doesn't have to move their eyes to the line below the question title? Maybe not.

Comment: @Pëkka I think you're being unreasonable. OF COURSE WE SHOULD CHANGE IT. CHANGE IS FOR THE GOOD. STOP LIVING IN THE PAST MAN. LEARN TO ACCEPT CHANGE. BECOME CHANGE. EMBRACE CHANGE. LOVE CHANGE. EVENTUALLY YOU WILL BE COME CHANGE

Comment: @Pëkka Yeah, basically this though.

Comment: I am not suggesting changing anything. The existing policy is that the preference is for languages to be tag-only, but it is not a requirement. I am just suggesting writing up the existing policy in more detail to give guidance for situations in which the language should be in the title, which in my opinion should be when the language involved is not a top-10 language.

Answer (score 1):

Like Robert Harvey suggested in the comments, just add those tags you definitely don't want to see to your ignore list. I recommend selecting the radio button to hide them, instead of grey them out, so you don't have to ever see those questions with the tags you ignored.

Yes, it takes some time to add the right amount of ignore tags, but it's definitely worth it.

[image]

Also, if you don't want to use the ignore tags, you can always do the http://stackexchange.com filtering options. I haven't used that personally, but I guess it is easier to set up then adding a lot of ignore tags.

Also, I see titles in questions a lot. Some get removed, while others remain. As far as I'm aware, there is not a strict rule on it. But either way, I don't see how you could force people asking questions to always enter their obscure coding language/tag in the title anyhow.

Just look at the tags on the question before entering the question. Plus, you can always read the first sentence or two of the post in the snippet it shows under the title, which can give you more info on if you should enter or not.

Comment: LOL, that is pretty funny. Nice idea, but in my case I am not interested in excluding all questions involving obscure tools and languages, I just want to warned up front when they are involved. For example, one question just posted had the title as "MatLab: loop to remove repeated elements of a vector and add corresponding elements of another vector". If this title had not included the Matlab notice, I might have accidentally looked at it thinking it was about generic vectors. Good title. Now, sometimes there are Matlab questions I can answer, so I don't want to exclude all Matlab questions.